# Can't log in Ubuntu 16.04 using Nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: drivers, upgrade, login-screen, 16.04, nvidia-geforce

I've recently upgraded from ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. Here him my laptop details:

- Acer Inspire V nitro 17
- Nvidia GeForce 860M
- RAM 6Gb

As I was using nvidia driver on 15.10, after the upgrade I couldn't log in again :making a loop back to the login screen
I've find an alternative by using :

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

I was then able to log in but I didn't have all my features working (like live wallpaper photoslide or screenlets)
However I've been looking for solutions and one of them was to:

- reinstall nvidia driver through command lines with

> sudo apt-get install nvidia-361

(361 is my version)

- Disable the secure boot

After that I have now a black screen at logging but I can still hear the sound.

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all of the suggestions, apart the fresh install, and none have worked

Comment: What doesn't work? Same issue, or something new?

Comment: No same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Uh oh. Did you run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` (ie no `-` before the `*`)? That removes system packages. Try running `sudo apt-get install -f`, but I don't have much hope for it working. You'll probably just have to reinstall.

Comment: I've already tried without the hyphen. But can I try to repair it with a new ISO (i.e on a usb) without losing all my data?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you choose the `Something Else` option when prompted and choose to mount your Ubuntu partition as `/`, it should overwrite all system files, while keeping `/home` (your data) intact.

Comment: I'll try that at least. I'll keep looking.

Comment: possible duplication of http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics?lq=1   ik that @Zacharee1 already said but i'm a flagspammer XD (jk)

Comment: install -f nvidia-361

haven't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a complete fresh install. And every thing was ok. But i had some trouble when installing gnome environment and ended up giving it up. So be aware.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had

- purged nvidia drivers
- logged in using the default graphical mode
- chosen my nvidia driver version (361 for me) in the Additional Drivers tab located in the Software & Updates window
- launched the nvidia X server settings and had chosen Intel (Power saving Mode) in the Prime Profiles
- logged out and in to validate the profile change
- rebooted and I was able to logged in.

PROBLEMS :

- When I had checked in the Additional Drivers tab, even if the nvidia driver-361 was checked, it still says that "This device is using an alternative driver".
  Maybe it's due to the profile I've chosen...I really don't know why.
- I still can't use the nvidia proprietary drivers normally.
  So still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

the problem, for me, seemed to be that my first install was using legacy, after installing in UEFI and turning off secure boot, i was able to add the nvidia ppa and install nvidia-364. beware nvidia-361